# R - More elegant way of writing line of code

Tags: r

Ok so lets take this code below which calculates a rolling simple moving average over 2 day period:

```
# Use TTR package to create rolling SMA n day moving average 
new.df$close.sma.n2 <- SMA(new.df[,"Close"], 2)
```

Lets say I want to calculate the n day period of 2:30

The inputs here is:

close.sma.n** 
and also the numerical value for the SMA calculation.

So my question is: 
How can I write one line of code to perform the above calculation on different SMA periods and also making a new column with corresponding close.sma.n2,3,4,5,6 etc value in a data frame?

I understand I can do:

```
n.sma <- 2:30
```

and put that variable in:

```
new.df$close.sma.n2 <- SMA(new.df[,"Close"], n.sma)
```

Perhaps I can:

```
name <- "n2:30"
```

and place that inside:

```
 new.df$close.sma.name <- SMA(new.df[,"Close"], n.sma)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide sample data or SMA, so I made up dummy functions to test my code.

```
df <- data.frame(Close=c(1, 2, 3, 4))
SMA <- function(x, numdays) {numdays}
```

Then, I wrote a function that takes in the number of days to average, and returns a function that takes a data.frame and takes the SMA over that many days.

```
getSMA <- function(numdays) {
  function(new.df) {
    SMA(new.df[,"Close"], numdays)
  }
}
```

Then, create a matrix to put the SMAs in

```
smas <- matrix(nrow=nrow(df), ncol=0)
```

and fill it.

```
for (i in 2:30) {
  smas <- cbind(smas, getSMA(i)(df))
}
```

Then, set the column names to what you want them to be

```
colnames(smas) <- sapply(2:30, function(n)paste("close.sma.n", n, sep=""))
```

and bind it with the starting data frame.

```
df <-  cbind(df, smas)
```

Now you have your original data.frame, plus `"close.sma.n2" through ".n30"`

Comment: Awesome!! :D This saves me a lot of duplicate line writing

Comment: Glad to help! In general, using functions that create functions is often hard to wrap your head around, but can be very useful when you want to do very repetitive but slightly different things. Look into Hadley Wickam's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) book for more

Comment: Ok great, this is my next learning curve with this (function / loops), I have some good basics down and it seems every time I use R I learn something new, or re validate what ive done before or understand it more. I will check it out the book for sure